# Lexicographic anticyclic rule: problem with utiliy function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

> Hey, I am supposed to Solve the following LPs by Simplex Method using
> lexicographic anticyclic rule.
>
> $4x_{1}+3x_{2}+8x_{3}+5x_{4}+6x_{5}\rightarrow min$
>
> $2x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}-x_{4}+2x_{5}\leq 2$
>
> $3x_{1}+0x_{2}+3x_{3}+3x_{4}+3x_{5}\leq 3$
>
> $4x_{1}+2x_{2}+8x_{3}+4x_{4}-3x_{5}\leq 4$
>
> $x_{1-5}\geq 0$

So I convert it to standard form:

$4x_{1}+3x_{2}+8x_{3}+5x_{4}+6x_{5}\rightarrow min$

$2x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}-x_{4}+2x_{5}+r_{1}=2$

$3x_{1}+0x_{2}+3x_{3}+3x_{4}+3x_{5}+r_{2}= 3$

$4x_{1}+2x_{2}+8x_{3}+4x_{4}-3x_{5}++r_{3}= 4$

$x_{1-5}\geq 0$, $r_{1-3}\geq 0$

But how am I supposed to solve it, if in utility function there is no negative variable and according to Lexicographic anticyclic rule I have no column to choose.

Thanks

Comment: If you minimize the objective function the coefficients of the obj. function are usually positive in the table. So you have no problem. Choose the column $x_1$

Comment: @callculus but Lexicographic anticyclic rule says that I have to choose an arbitrary column with $c_j < 0$ and there is no such

Comment: OK, it seems it refers to a maximum problem. Do you know in general how so solve a min-problem?

Comment: $\textrm{min} \, f(x)=\textrm{max} \, \, -f(x)$

Comment: @callculus okay, so it means, that I will transfer utility function to max, just with opposite sign?

Comment: Yes, then you choose the first column as pivot column. The pivot row can be one of the three rows since $\min\left(\frac{2}{2}, \frac{3}{3}, \frac{4}{4}, \right)=1$ The objective function become negative. At the end take the absolute value of it.

Comment: @callculus thank you so much, you helped a lot

Comment: That pleases me. You´re welcome.